# Castle Windsor: Best way to log when a component is registered?

Tags: logging, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I would like to log when a component (interface and implementation) is registered to my container.  What is the best way of doing this?

I found the IKernelEvents interface that looks promising but I can't find how to actually use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, found that IKernel implements IKernelEvents

Therefore simply

```
WindsorContainer.Kernel.ComponentRegistered += (k, h) => _logger.Debug("Registered {0} - {1}/{2}", k, h.ComponentModel.Service.FullName, h.ComponentModel.Implementation.FullName);
```