# Interfaces are in a different project as implementations, castle not wiring up propertly

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-windsor

My Interfaces are in a seperate project, and I'm guessing I have to do something special when I am registering my services etc. in windsor.

The error I am getting is:

```
Type ABC.Interfaces.Services.IUserService is abstract.
As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of service ABC.Interfaces.Services.IUserService.
```

My installer:

```
 public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                    AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<UserService>()
                    .BasedOn<IUserService>()
                    .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                    .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Singleton));
        }

    container.Register(
                    AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<UserRepository>()
                    .BasedOn<IUserRepository>()
                    .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                    .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest)
                    );
```

I was getting the error, and then I added the `.BasedOn<....>()` clause as I figured it has to do with my interfaces being in a separate project (and thus assembly) as the actual implementation.

**Do I have to tell castle the assembly of that interface?
Or is something else the issue?**

**Update II**

My code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        private IUserService _userService;

        public HomeController(IUserService userService)
        {
            this._userService = userService;
        }

}
```

In services assembly:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private IUserRepository _repository;

        public UserService(IUserRepository repository)
        {
            this._repository = repository;
        }


        public void Create(IUser user)
        {
            _repository.Create(user);
        }
        public IUser Get(int id)
        {
            return _repository.Get(id);
        }

    }
```

In interfaces assembly:

```
public interface IUserService
{
        void Create(IUser user);
        IUser Get(int id);
}
```

Comment: I think something else is the issue.  The only place it should care about the assembly is enumerating the types to use as candidate implementations (the `.FromAssembly...` part).  Kinda would break one of the most useful scenarios, otherwise (contract assemblies) :)

Comment: I see, then I'm really stuck.  I hate this :_

Comment: can you show declaration of IUserService and UserService?

Comment: @Davide I updated with code thanks.

Comment: the error clearly says that the container tries to bind the interface to itself. while the code looks for implementations in specific assembly (.FromAssemblyContaining<UserService>()), if i were you, i would treat the error literally and would try to make sure windsor does not try to bind interface to itself.

Comment: @ivan what do you mean treat that error literally? I'm new to this.

Comment: @Blankman: are you sure IUserService is defined NOT in assembly where UserService defined? i would try to enumerate over AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<UserService>().BasedOn<IUserService>().Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service")) collection and show debug message for every type falling under the condition. i suspect there would be some types you do not expect to see there :)

Comment: @ivan yes I am sure, this is a simple project that I coded 100%.  All my interfaces are in a seperate vs.net project, and the UserServices is in a different project/assembly also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [**BasedOn**, **Where**, and **Pick** do logical **or**](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#Additional_filtering_and_configuration_4)

So this code:

```
AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<UserService>()
    .BasedOn<IUserService>()
    .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
```

Will select all types that are based on `IUserService`, or end with `Service`.  The type `IUserService` ends with `Service`, so it gets selected for registration.

To solve this, you can remove the `EndsWith("Service")` filtering.  It probably isn't necessary anyway.  Or you could remove the `BasedOn` filter, and move similar logic to the `Where` clause:

```
AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<UserService>()
    .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Service")
        && typeof(IUserService).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    .WithService.DefaultInterface()
    .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Singleton)
```

Also, you say the types are in different assemblies, but it seems somehow you are grabbing types out of the assembly that `IUserService` lives in.

Check out [this question for a way to debug which services are getting registered by your code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167766/castle-windsor-best-way-to-log-when-a-component-is-registered)

Comment: Actually my goal was to wire up all classes ending with Service, like UserService, ContentService, etc. and they all have interfaces like IUserService and IContentService, how can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm browsing through the 2.4 code right now.  I don't know that a logical-and is supported, unless explicitly written in a `where`'s predicate.  Edited the question to solve this problem still, tho.

Comment: Note that when I had both clauses, a quick trial app I wrote also failed to run.  When I removed either of them it started working again.

Comment: but when you put && typeof(IUserService) that's not written in a generic way i.e. it won't work for IContentService or IPostService etc.

Comment: @Blankman: No it isn't generic.  Nor is what you wrote before (`.BasedOn<IUserService>()`).  I'm trying to resolve the error you're getting.  Multiple service registration is a different question.  BTW, it is a bad idea to try to write a registrar with no policies (e.g. trying to suck in every type and register it with its default interface).  You'll run into too many errors.  It is better to support specifically the scenarios you want to support (things that derive from specific interfaces) so you can limit your service registration debugging scope.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the same error, 
but I forgot to add the wcf facility.

```
container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>();
```